# Lyrics of "Heroin" by The Lurkers

Tags: lyrics, punk

Dunno if I should go to some English SE site instead, but:

I'm a German and my English is quite OK after 60 years, but who shall understand this accent if not being a native? Also, punk rock. I only "get" fragments. Here is a video: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0pMt7Di6HU). Astonishingly the lyrics are not on the 'Net (or my Google Fu was weak). Someone having the liner notes would be optimal.

Comment: Hey man, I've never heard that song before, it's really quite good. He found his mate dead in his car from Heroin, it sounds like. "I never seen a face that gray, her-o-in". Can't find lyrics, but you could just write them down, maybe even start a lyric sheet on a lyrics website yourself and maybe other people will add to it.